# Where does the variable from closure with NEW value is stored?

Tags: javascript

Part 1
There is the rule in JS functions, that we destroy the local execution context after its done, every time with all variables in it.

So i cant understand in example below:
where does the counter variable from closure with **NEW value** is stored to be used in c2 and next, with **NEW value** again - in c3?

Part 2

```
c1 = (counter = 0, counter = counter + 1) is 1;
c2 = (counter = 1, counter = counter + 1) is 2;
c3 = (counter = 2, counter = counter + 1) is 3;
```

example increment 1, 2, 3

```
    function createCounter() {
    let counter = 0;
    const myFunction = function () {
        counter = counter + 1;
        return counter;
    };
    return myFunction;
    }
    const increment = createCounter();
    const c1 = increment();
    const c2 = increment();
    const c3 = increment();
    console.log('example increment', c1, c2, c3);
```

I expect explanation of steps in part 2 in context of my question in part 1.

Comment: `I expect explanation` - it's fun to expect things :p what do you know about closures? the value is stored in `counter` - if you don't understand that, read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 1):

---

### **EDIT**

A more in-depth explanation of how exactly your particular example works:

First you need to understand how Javascript scopes work.  Any object or variable or function created within the scope of a function is then available within that function and any sub-functions defined therein.

```
function someFunction() { 
  var g = "Hello!"; // g is available to everything within someFunction
  g = "goodbye"; // change the value of g
  return g; // returns "goodbye"
}
```

That variable is not available to functions outside of the scope of that function. (from another function).

If the variable is defined as a static type (such as a string, number, array, or object)  then it is returned as such.   So,  in this example:

```
myfunction() { 
   let a = 1;
   return a;
}

var b = myfunction(); // b = 1
```

-

Most people can grasp this concept.  Its fairly easy.  The real question that you are asking is:  ***what happens when a function is returned instead of a value?***

Lets look at another example:

```
function myFunction() { 
   var a = 1;
   function  myNestedFunction() { 
      a++;
      return a;
   }
   return myNestedFunction;
}
```

Since we know that functions inside of other functions have access to all of the things (variables, functions, etc)  which are defined within the top-level function (according to the first part of this answer).
Therefore, by definition, the function `myNestedFunction()`  has access to the variable `a`  which was defined in its parent function.

The parent function then returns `myNestedFunction`  which is treated as a type of element, which can then be accessed by using the function's `()`  parameters.  Since `myNestedFunction` has access to `a` from `myFunction`, instead of returning `1` each time, you can set `myNestedFunction` to point towards a different variable  and re-evaluate it without re-setting the `a` variable.

```
function myFunction() { 
   var a = 1;
   function  myNestedFunction() { 
      a++;
      return a;
   }
   return myNestedFunction;
}

var c = myFunction(); //   c = myNestedFunction, within it a=1
var d = c();    // d =  2  because myNestedFunction does a++ then returns a
var e = c();     // d = 3
```

You're welcome and thank you for your patience.

Comment: **"...being that a function is returned it becomes a closure."** That is it. I understand how it works, but i dont understand why.

Comment: Because in javascript functions are first class entities. You can return a value from a function then access that value via that function or even return a function from a function and access that function via the first function

Comment: in your example, myFunction is being returned by  createCounter, which sets counter to 0 and gives you a way to access the counter variable since it is defined within the scope of createCounter()

Answer (score 1):

> Part 1
>   There is the rule in JS functions, that we destroy the local execution context after its done, every time with all variables in it.

No, there’s no such rule.  The real rule is that calling the function again will establish a different execution context, which is a totally different beast.  The execution context is actually thrown away when it is no longer reachable.  Since you have a reference to a function that uses that execution context, it won’t get destroyed until you no longer have that reference.

Unlike other languages that pass variables using a single, global, stack, javascript uses its stack space to hold execution contexts, where parameters are their own thing within the larger execution context.

It might help you to think of every function call as either a new object or an existing object, depending upon where and how it is called. In the case of a closure, it’s a call into an existing object.